# How to launch application as early as possible on user logon in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, boot

I need to launch app on user logon in windows 8 as early as possible, ideally before other apps assigned to launch during user logon. Where should I register it ?

UPDATE: What I'm trying to find out is order in which various sources of autoloading are processed, specifically what source is processed first in the context of user logon

Comment: If you meant applications/services at start-up.. well you may be able to use system configuration utility and edit the startup tab according to your needs. to launch the utility simply search for `msconfig` and launch it. there you'll find start-up tab, check whether the program is listed.. and if so, just tick it which will automate the process. :)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to achieve. Here's a TechNet tip to "[Understand and Control Startup Apps with the System Configuration Utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee851671.aspx)"

You could just put it in the 'Start-up' / 'Startup' folder : `C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` and be done with it.

Or you could go the Registry route if you so choose. Open Registry Editor from `Run` with `RegEdit` then navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Mircosoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`. Create a new string value by right-clicking then selecting 'New'. Enter application's name as the value's name and the application's path as the data.

Let me know if either of these solutions help you or not.

Comment: What I'm trying to find out is order in which this sources are processed, specifically what source is processed first in the context of user logon.

Comment: Then I guess I was way off base, try [Autoruns from Systinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx). I might be mistaken, but I believe that `C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` is the first to start in the case of user logon.