# What is the first user-definable startup script on Windows 8+?

Tags: windows-8, boot

There are a lot of places one can insert a system-wide command to run on startup: registry, GPO, Task Scheduler, etc.. Does anyone know what the first place is that a boot script can be set? Bonus points for a list of all the places in sequential order.

I *don't* mean per-user or as-user, but system-wide. I *do* mean repeatable, upon every boot--not a one-time script. I'm asking with Windows 8.1 in mind but I'm not sure if this stuff has changed drastically since Win7 or earlier.

Comment: It hasn't changed.

Comment: Huh? Why the downvote?

Comment: Question seems sort of broad.  There are also lots of existing questions on how to control what is started when a user logs into their profile, many contain much of the information you are looking, and where and what you edit really has not changed in over a decade.

Comment: I disagree. I found none that indicated which method happened first or in what order they run. I also don't think it's broad at all, it specifically asks which startup method that a user can set happens first. Whether it has changed or not doesn't seem relevant to the order in which they happen--and which happens first, which is the question.

Comment: Additionally, even if the answer to this question is buried in some other question, that question's comments or unaccepted answers, or multiple questions, assembled together, I think there is value in having a separate question that is specifically and obviously for this purpose.

Comment: You asked the reason for the downvote, I was kind enough, to provide a reason.  I hope I won't regret that.

Comment: I've actually wanted the answer to this exact question before, I countered the down vote.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to launch application as early as possible on user logon in windows 8](http://superuser.com/questions/701893/how-to-launch-application-as-early-as-possible-on-user-logon-in-windows-8).

Comment: Almost, but that question is specifically about the earliest point at which one can run a script during user logon, and I'm looking for system startup.